# Consul health checker

Tags: java, consul, consul-health-check

I have consul agent server on localhost:8500.
Then I have a simple http server, which first registrates in consul

```
    Consul client = Consul.builder().build(); // connect on localhost
    AgentClient agentClient = client.agentClient();

    String serviceId = "1";
    Registration.RegCheck regCheck = ImmutableRegCheck.builder()
            .http("localhost:8080/api/rocks/healthCheck")
            .interval("5s")
            .timeout("1s")
            .build();
    Registration service = ImmutableRegistration.builder()
            .id(serviceId)
            .name("myService")
            .port(8080)
            .check(regCheck) // registers with a TTL of 3 seconds
            .tags(Collections.singletonList("tag1"))
            .meta(Collections.singletonMap("version", "1.0"))
            .build();

    agentClient.register(service);
```

And I it answers on get request for "healthCheck"

```
@GetMapping(value = "/healthCheck")
public ResponseEntity<String> healthCheck() {
    log.info("RocksApi.healthCheck");
    return ResponseEntity.ok("ok");
}
```

But consuls's health checker still says that Check is now critical for my service

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your healthcheck URL might be wrong. In your client builder you say "api/rocks/healthCheck" but your endpoint is only reachable via path "/healthCheck".